# Php variables is not showing up in the mail

Tags: php, html, email, smtp, wampserver

I'm building a website that I run under a `Wamp server 3` and I have a php contact form that i want the visitors to be able to mail directly from the website.

```
<?php

$myemail  = "test.xample@xample.com";

if (isset($_POST['email'])) 
{
    echo "Thank you for contacting us!";

    /* Set e-mail recipient */

    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $subject  = ($_POST['subject']);
    $email    = ($_POST['email']);
    $message = ($_POST['message']);
    $mail = "Hello!

    Your contact form has been submitted by:

    Name: $name
    E-mail: $email

    Message:
    $Message

    End of message
    ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
}
?>
```

I have tested the code by run a `SMTP Server` and the `mail()` function and everything working but my problem is that my variables `$name, $message, $email` is not showing up in the mail

This is what the mail should look like:

```
$mail = "Hello!

    Your contact form has been submitted by:

    Name: $name
    E-mail: $email

    Message:
    $Message

    End of message
    ";
```

But the outcome of the mail looks like this:

> Hello!
>
> Your contact form has been submitted by:
>
> Name:
>
> E-mail:
>
> Message:
>
> End of message

So the values of the variables is empty...

This is the html of the form:

```html
<form class="mt-5 ml-5 mr-5" method="POST" action="handler.php" id="reused_form">
  <p id="contactForm" class="h4 text-center mt-5"><strong>Kontakta oss</strong></p>

  <!-- input text(Name) -->
  <div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-user prefix">*</i>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
    <label for="name">Your name</label>
  </div>

  <!-- input email -->
  <div class="md-form mt-5">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix">*</i>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control validate">
    <label for="email" data-error="Wrong" data-success="Right">Your email</label>
  </div>

  <div class="md-form mt-5">
    <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
    <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control">
    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
  </div>

  <!-- input message -->
  <div class="md-form mt-5">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil prefix">*</i>
    <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message" maxlength="5000" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
    <label for="textareaPrefix">Message</label>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">
    <button class="btn danger-color" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Would be very pleased if someone could help me with this problem...

Comment: $message != $Message

Comment: Oh thats right... but it dosen't work anyway :( @FatFreddy

Answer (score 1):

Remove these braces () at post like below

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

and mail as below
     mail($myemail, $subject, $mail);

Comment: I will test and come back with an answer as soon as possible :)

Comment: did you check whether the data is posted or not? try keeping print_r($_POST); die; and check what it is showing there

Comment: in the browser, in handler.php page

Comment: Oh! I have right now just a message that says `Thanks for contacting` if it is submitted. So the variables should show up under that?

Comment: ok, I have lunch in 40 min, so I'll go home and test that then :) Thanks for the answer

Comment: Where in my `php` should be the best place to have it?

Comment: keep it above if condition and test

Comment: This is the output I get:  `Array ( [name] => Ludde [email] => ludde.pantza@outlook.com [subject] => Subject [message] => Hello [submit] => )`

Comment: great, data is posting fine. can you try to echo your $mail like echo $mail; die; just before this line mail($myemail, $subject, $message); check whether it is echoing all the data correctly

Comment: Nooo... The output is : ` Ditt kontakt formulär har blivit besvarat av: Namn: E-mail: Kundens meddelande: Meddelande slut.` So the variables don't follow :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173535/discussion-between-sree-and-luddep).

Answer (score 0):

Debugging 101:

Check that the variables are being posted as expected. Add a var_dump option

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) 
{
   var_dump( $_POST );
```

If all is correct then check the values after processing:

```
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $subject  = ($_POST['subject']);
    $email    = ($_POST['email']);
    $message = ($_POST['message']);
    var_dump( $name, $subject, $email, $message );
```

If all is correct then ensure that the variables are processed by enclosing them in curly brackets.

```
$mail = "Hello!

    Your contact form has been submitted by:

    Name: $name
    E-mail: {$email}

    Message:
    {$Message}

    End of message
    ";
```

There are other 'problems' with your code as you are not checking or sanitising the data before sending it on.

Comment: Okey, I'll test and come back with an answer as soon as possible :) And i have the data check but I didn't add that in the question because I saw that as unnecessary...

Comment: It's not working with the debugger... When I try to debug I get a promt that says `Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH`